# Show that if $ X $ has the property $ \mathcal{M} $, then $ X $ is locally connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, locally-connected

Let $ (X, \tau) $ be a topological space. We will say that $ X $ has the property $ \mathcal{M} $ if every open coverage of $ X $ admits a finite refinement consisting of connected sets.

Show that if $ X $ has the property $ \mathcal{M} $, then $ X $ is locally connected.

**Proof:**
Let $ U \subset X $ open with $ x \in U $ arbitrary, let us take $ \{U \} $ the open coverage, that by hypothesis there is a finite refinement of connected sets, that is: $x \in \bigcup_{i = 1}^{n} C_i \subset U$ with $ C_i $ connected for each $ i = \{1, \cdots, n \} $, since the finite union of connected is connected, then $ X $ is locally connected.

Please any suggestion for the demo. Thanks!

Comment: The finite union of connected sets is not necessarily connected, for example the union of two disjoint intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. $\{U\}$ is not an open cover of $X$.

Comment: Yes it's correct! if $ \bigcup_{\alpha} C_ {\alpha} = X $ with $ C_{\alpha} $ connected, for $ X $ to be connected it is required that $ C_{\alpha} \cap C_{\alpha '} \neq \emptyset.$ Any help you want to give me?

Comment: The same question has been asked before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3870887 If you fill the gaps (see my comments to the referenced question), you may perhaps receive an answer. Until clarification I vote to close your question.